# Java Script, может с БД работать?

Tags: javascript, mysql

Java Script, может с MySQL работать? без перезагрузки страницы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Напрямую - нет. Если конечно Вы имеете виду браузерный JavaScript. Только через AJAX. Но в этом случае с MySQL будет работать серверая технология (например PHP). JavaScript -> PHP -> MySQL

Answer (score 2):

Серверный javascript( Nodejs ) - может, клиентский ( напрямую ) - нет, что логично собственно, БД не проходной двор а, подразумевается, что это ценная информация и естественно клиент напрямую, по определению, не должен иметь никакого доступа.

Конечно javascript может взаимодествовать с сервером с помощью аякса, но суть в том что это всеравно не прямое взаимодействие.